# Placing image inside a Div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place an image inside of a div, but when I do so it doesn't display at all. I've created the image myself and made the div to fit. Currently with max-width and max-height I can get it to display inside the box but only at a fraction of the size.

My current code is...

HTML

```
<div id="carousel">
    <img src="Images/carousel1.png" alt="#" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#carousel {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px, #000;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your image is what the problem is? What is the sizing of your image?

Comment: 1280 x 300, i created it in Illustrator and made the div the same size

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that the path to the image is correct. Check the console and see if you have any errors.

Than, remove the inline style on the `img` tag and add in the css file:

```
#carousel img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that, but I'm still having an issue, the image width is correct although it's not quite 100%, but the height is making it look like it is being compressed. Any ideas?

Comment: The only problem i could think why its distorting it in such a way is the clipping mask I've used to crop a certain segment of the image, but that shouldn't affect the png when saved surely?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply the `width: 100%` and height `100%` to your image tag and not only your container div.
check this out  : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqzXoR